# How can I position form elements equally in all browsers regardless of window size.

Tags: html, css

Here is my form code:

```
<td align="center" style=" width=50%; height=50%; background: url(images/side.gif) repeat-x ;">
<img src="images/iphone.gif" width="670" height="549" alt="">
<img style="position:fixed; left:280px; bottom:50px;"src="spr2.png" width="2%" height="15%" alt="">
<form style="display:inline-block;" method="POST" action="index.php">
<label style="position:fixed; left: 200px; bottom: 130px;">: اسم المستخدم</label>
<input style="position:fixed; left:50px; bottom:130px;" type="text" name="username" size="20"><br>
<label style="position:fixed; left:200px; bottom:100px;">: كلمة المرور</label>
<input style="position:fixed; left:50px; bottom:100px;" type="password" name="password" size="20"><br>
<input style="position:fixed; left:50px; bottom:60px;" type="submit" value=" تسجيل دخول ">
</form>
</td>
```

Here are screen shots from different browsers:

[image]

The elements change position when I resize the window:

[image]

How can I prevent the elements from changing position and width?

Comment: Why don't you declare the width for the input elements by css?

Comment: please give example, because I am beginner in html/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the width issue, try utilizing the `width`, like in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nq7tK/4/).

```
<input type="text" style="width:200px;" size="20">
<input type="text" style="width:200px;" size="40">​
```

Your problem with `position` might stem from the fact that you're using the value of `fixed`. [Absolute positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) inside of relative positioning might be more like what you're going for.

Comment: thank you, the width problem solved. but the position still exist even when I changed fixed to absolute

Comment: Is the parent element set to `relative` positioning?

Comment: The parent is the TD element, and all of his styles appear to be inline.

Comment: @jmeas I made the <td> as relative, but to locate the input element I have to make in minus. worked fine with safari and opera, but very bad with firefox

Answer (score 1):

You are positioning elements on your page in a way that ignores the normal flow of relative positioning. By specifying `left: 200px;` and `position:fixed;` you are saying that no matter how your page is resized, or where you scroll to, the element will always be 200px from the left side of the window. Notice how even though you have `<br>` tags after your textboxes, you still have the labels directly to the right of them.

Use relative positioning - `position:relative;` or just remove the position attribute. Then use padding and margins to space out your elements, or float them. And if they are not showing up horizontally in a line, then change the `display` attribute to `inline-block`, and on the labels use `clear:right;` or put a `<br>` after them.

Put your styles in and external file.

Something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/R7RRH/2/

Comment: thank you for your great explanation, but really I can't understand it .